# Matplotlib data corruption when using threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, matplotlib

I have a very large amount of data to graph, with each set of data requiring its own independent graph. I am using threads to one grab data and the other to graph it, however I keep having the data change during an iteration.

I've tried thread locks in multiple different positions to try and make sure my data isn't changing while its being plotted. However, this has proven unsuccessful. I guess I've just had the locks in the wrong place.

```
sheet = excel_sheets[1]
print(sheet.cell_value(0,1))

lock = threading.Lock()

def exampleJob(worker):

        #lock.acquire()
        dct = worker[0]
        time_values = worker[1]
        x_labels = worker[2]
        for i in dct:
            plt.figure()
            plt.scatter(time_values, dct[i])
            plt.title(i)
            plt.xlabel("Time")
            plt.ylabel("% CPU Utilization")
            plt.xticks(x_labels,rotation=90)
            plt.show()
        #lock.release()

def threader():
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        worker = q.get()
        exampleJob(worker)
        q.task_done()
        lock.release()

q = Queue()

for x in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

start = time.time()

time_values = [xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell_value(i,0), wb.datemode).strftime('%H:%M:%S') for i in range(1,sheet.nrows)]

x_labels = [i for i in range(0,(len(time_values)-1),128)]

dct = {}
for i in range(1,sheet.ncols):
    dct['{}' .format(sheet.cell_value(0,i))] = [sheet.cell_value(j,i) for j in range(1,sheet.nrows)]
    q.put((dct, time_values, x_labels))

q.join()
```

So this is essentially the structure that I have been using. However, when I try to graph the dct and its data, I get an error saying that the dct data has changed during the for loop. I think there are some other errors going on, but I believe all errors are related to the data being improperly protected.

Comment: Maybe try creating a new dictionary on each iteration instead of modifying the same dictionary on every iteration: move `dct = {}` to the first line of the for loop suite.

Comment: Wow that was all it took...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix, pointed out to me by wwii in the comments. So the answer is this:

```
for i in range(1,sheet.ncols):
    dct = {}
    dct['{}' .format(sheet.cell_value(0,i))] = [sheet.cell_value(j,i) for j in range(1,sheet.nrows)]
    q.put((dct, time_values, x_labels))
```